# Android image size (portrait only) for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently work on an android project that the app is force to portrait only, I already have some design pictures and I would like to cut the image to build the UI. However, the problem is how should I scale each picture?

What I found so far

```
xlarge (xhdpi): 640x960
large (hdpi): 480x800
medium (mdpi): 320x480
small (ldpi): 240x320
```

But I also found

```
hdpi = mdpi * 1.5
xhdpi = mdpi * 2
xxhdpi = mdpi *3
```

but actually  the mdpi * 1.5 should be 480 * 720 ? How should I resize the picture for each resolution? thanks

Comment: Here is an answer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those resolutions are only guidelines not absolutes, and represent a general amount of pixels in each dpi "bucket". I'd primarily use the scaling factors instead. So whatever your image's resolution, scale appropriately.  For instance, my raw image files are always designed as the xxhdpi version.  Then I scale down by 3, 2, and 1.5 for the lower dpi versions.

Comment: Thanks. but what should be use for the "base image"? for instance, if you use the xxhdpi for the base , then what is the size of xxhdpi? thanks

Comment: Depends.  Some things like ActionBar icons have a predefined size by Google.  http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: Otherwise, you'll just have to play around with what looks good. Try to get away from building to exact pixel measurements.  The scaling is designed so that it does not matter what dpi a device is.  All images will take up the same amount of physical space

Comment: For instance 48x48dp is recommended for anything touchable. That corresponds to 7-10 mm of actual screen space...no matter the devices dpi.  http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Comment: Sorry for new to android design , as I was doing programming stuff only before. Is the approach like that ? e.g. 1) has a 1920 * 1080 design image, 2) cut the icon ,background etc... 3) scale down the cut image (xhdpi = xxhdpi / 1.5 , hdpi = xxhdpi / 2 , mdpi = xxhdpi/3)...

Comment: yeah it can be confusing at first.  Approach sounds good. You can generate icon sized images very easily by using this website.  It'll auto scale to all the dpi versions for you: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example

Comment: Hi! Have we scale base image using code or images should be scales?